Image width issue in css
I have 3 images which should appear in a row side by side. However the first image is big and it pushes the other two images to next row which I don't want. I have made a class and added height and width but its not working.


.workImgs {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100vw;
  max-width: 100rem;    
}

.workImg {
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 20rem;
  margin: 0.5rem;
}
<div class="workImgs">
  <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="https://picsum.photos/245/182" alt="" class="workImg" /></a>
  <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="https://picsum.photos/185/184" alt="" class="workImg" /></a>
  <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="https://picsum.photos/184/165" alt="" class="workImg" /></a>
</div>



This is the result UI. I want the first img width to be equal to rest 2 so that they can be in 1 row. Have tried creating diff id for big img but didn't work.


Don't use flex-wrap: wrap and maybe give them a flex: 1 1 33% or something. In this case a grid with grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr might be what you are looking for.

Also, margin is calculated in addition to width. So even if you your elements were 33.3333% wide, you'd need to subtract the margin from that percentage, like calc(33.3333% - 1rem) (1 since you need to account for both left and right margin)

Simply give the images a width of 100% and remove the flex-wrap to prevent wrapping, which will force the a elements to their maximum size, and they won't be larger because the images take the maximum width.


.workImgs {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.workImg {
  object-fit: cover;
  margin: 0.5rem;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
<div class="workImgs">
  <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="https://picsum.photos/245/182" alt="" class="workImg" /></a>
  <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="https://picsum.photos/185/184" alt="" class="workImg" /></a>
  <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="https://picsum.photos/184/165" alt="" class="workImg" /></a>
</div>




There are several mistakes in your code. Regarding your question, you should specify the width of your images when you set their height. When images increase in height, their width also increases to maintain the same aspect ratio until they reach that height. So, the width increases as well.
If you want to keep your images in one row, you should set flex-wrap to nowrap and avoid using margins. When you set a width, margins are excluded from that width. You can wrap all images in a container and set padding to them, or calculate the width using calc. For example: width: calc(33.3333% - 1rem). But in the first solution, don't forget to reset box-sizing to border-box.
<div className="image-container">
  <a href="https://github.com/aditya803/Flappy_Bird" target="_blank"><img src={FlappyBird} alt="" /></a>
  <a href="https://github.com/aditya803/flutter_firebase" target="_blank"><img src={BrewCrew} alt="" /></a>
  <a href="https://github.com/aditya803/news_app" target="_blank"><img src={NewsApp} alt="" /></a>
</div>

.image-container{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  width: 100vw;
  max-width: 100rem;    
}

.image-container img{
  object-fit: cover;
  margin: 0.5rem;
  width: 100%;
  /* or */  
  /* width: calc(100% - 1rem)  */

  /* to keep all images ratio same */
  aspect-ratio: 16/9;
}


One way to ensure that all three images appear in a row, regardless of the size of the first image, is to set a specific width for each image container, and then set the width of the images to 100% so that they are on their own. Fill the respective containers.


.workImgs {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.workImgContainer {
  flex: 1;
  max-width: 33.33%; /* Adjust according to your preference */
  margin: 0.5rem;
}

.workImgContainer img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: cover;
}
<div class="workImgs">
  <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="https://picsum.photos/245/182" alt="" class="workImg" /></a>
  <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="https://picsum.photos/185/184" alt="" class="workImg" /></a>
  <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="https://picsum.photos/184/165" alt="" class="workImg" /></a>
</div>




To ensure that all three images appear side by side in one row, you can set a fixed width for all images.


.workImgs {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  gap: 2px;
}

.workImgs > a {
  flex-basis: 33.33%;
}

.workImg {
  object-fit: cover;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
}
<div class="workImgs">
  <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="https://picsum.photos/245/182" alt="" class="workImg" /></a>
  <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="https://picsum.photos/185/184" alt="" class="workImg" /></a>
  <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="https://picsum.photos/184/165" alt="" class="workImg" /></a>
</div>




To have the first img width to be equal to rest 2 so that they can be in 1 row.
Give width 100% to the parent container and add gap of 0.25rem to distinguish between the images.
Now, apply the height and width to the a tag with display: block so that the image can fit in that.


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.workImgs {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  gap: 0.25rem;
}

a {
  display: block;
  width: 33%;
  height: 10rem;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.workImg {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
<div class="workImgs">
  <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="https://picsum.photos/245/182" alt="" class="workImg" /></a>
  <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="https://picsum.photos/185/184" alt="" class="workImg" /></a>
  <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="https://picsum.photos/184/165" alt="" class="workImg" /></a>
</div>




Try to remove flex-wrap: wrap; from .workImgs selector.
The Images should appear in a row.
